# Export only the Custom Element class with Angular Element

Tags: angular

With Angular Element it's possible to create a custom element from an angular component with `createCustomElement`.

For example:

```js
 const tabsNew = createCustomElement(TabsNewWayComponent, {injector: appRef.injector});
 customElements.define('tabs-new', tabsNew);
```

After building and merging the dist scripts **polyfills**, **main**, **runtime** i can use the component as a web component with the result script.

But i need to export only the class that extends HTMLElement.

It's possible to do that?

If i try to export the class of the web component generated in the dist but it change name every build, It's possible to specify the class that extend HTMLElement?